# Windows 7 : Share UMTS Internet via Ad-Hoc WLAN

Tags: networking

I have a problem with my WLAN ad-hoc mode. But first the details. I want to share my internet connection (UMTS  via USB) via the wireless lan interface in Win 7.

The first step was to activate the sharing for the UMTS interface which is done and the chosen device is the name of my wireless lan device.

The second step was to create a ad-hoc network which is also done. With my second mashine I can connect without getting a IP caused by no running DHCP Server.
So I tried to set satic IP addresses (the ad-hoc server 192.168.100.1 and the second mashine got ... .100.2). But I wasn't able to ping the server with my client.
Subnet is the standard one (255.255.255.0) no default Gateway for the host, the default gateway for the client was the ip address of the server. Where is my fault?
Maybe it is better to use a DHCP server? Which one is good?

Thanks for your help!

Bob

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to enable Internet Connection sharing on your wireless adapter (not the UTMS interface).  This [Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) has all the information you need.  An excerpt is below:

> To enable ICS, on your host computer:
>
> Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button , clicking
>   Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, clicking Network and
>   Sharing Center, and then clicking Manage network connections.
>
> Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click
>   Properties.   If you are prompted for an administrator password or
>   confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> Click the Sharing tab, and then select the Allow other network users
>   to connect through this computer’s Internet connection check box.
>
> Note
>
> The Sharing tab will not be available if you have only one network
>   connection.
>
> If desired, you can also select the Allow other network users to
>   control or disable the shared Internet connection check box.
>
> Optionally, to allow other network users to use services running on
>   your network, click Settings and select the services you want to
>   allow.

ICS has a built-in DHCP server that hands out IPs on a 192.168.x.x network.